# Is there a way to show loading sign in r shiny for rds file?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

When I read a rds file it can take some time after input upload function to completely upload the file. Can I show some sort of bar while that is happening. I know about css loaders but I am not sure in this case and I would like a bar but not necessary. The rds file that uploaded can be quite big like unto 10 GB so I would like to show something while the r console is saying busy. I hope you get my point.

```
data <- reactive({
  file <- input$rds
  ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
  req(file)
  validate(need(ext == "rds", "Please upload a rds file"))
  readRDS(file$datapath)
})
```

Comment: Why not shinycssloaders? If a bar isnt necessary, that seems like the perfect solution, no? Not sure about a progress bar.

Comment: I found the "infinite" options (for when you don't know the loading time in advance) of `waitress` and `hostess` from package **{waiter}** quite useful (https://waiter.john-coene.com/#/waitress#infinite). Still, it's a good idea to display a fair estimate of the loading time to the visitor ("This might take up to ...").